# curl not responding with Tika App as server

Tags: php, curl, apache-tika

I am creating a webservice in PHP and using Tika to drop files to text.  Initially, I processed each file through Tika in an external shell (fine for development, but does not scale), but am trying to now use Tika in server mode:

```
java -jar /path/to/tika-1.3-app.jar -s 5150 &
```

I am able to see the port being listened on, and send a file/receive parsed text using 'nc', however, when attempting the same via 'curl' it just hangs and never returns.  In verbose mode I can see the file upload being complete.  I have tried both -T and -F, all I see is "*Done waiting for 100-continue".

Am I missing an argument, or is there a certain header to send additionally?  The goal is to use cURL from the main PHP script to make the request (which also does not work at the moment), so if there is a better way overall, please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a very simple reason why the Tika App Network Server isn't playing nicely with Curl - it isn't HTTP based! It's a very simple network based protocol, normally used with something like netcat or the Tika App client, intended for testing / demos / prototyping. It's not really recommended for production.

Instead, you should be using the more fully featured [Tika JAXRS Server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS)? The latter offers more options, and is fully RESTful. You can use it nicely with curl (along with any other HTTP client), and there are plenty of [examples on the wiki with curl](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) to follow.

The [Tika JAXRS Server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS) exposes various Tika functions (text extraction, xhtml, metadata etc) via RESTful HTTP calls, and is the generally recommended way to interface Tika to a non-Java application over the network.

Comment: Dear lord. The very first sentence would have been all that was needed in the Tika guide, spent far too much time trying to find out what was going on.  I did go to the TikaJAXRS server, and it worked perfectly for what I need.